# Time drift with Windows IoT core

Tags: windows-iot

**The Problem** I have 4 Raspberry Pis running on my local network.  All 4 Raspberry Pis are posting messages every 5 seconds to an Azure IoT hub.

The problem is that when time drifts off, I'm getting authentication errors from the IoT hub and then my app crashes.

**I have noticed** that when connected via a network cable there is no issue.  But errors are much more common on WiFi. Using WiFi is the desired use case.

I have also observed that power cycling will not trigger Windows IoT to update the time, but a `restart` will.

**My current strategy** I want to trigger the same time update mechanism that happens on a `restart` but in a controlled manner.  I'm currently attempting to have a power-shell script run every hour to resync.

**Where I need help**  I'm trying to run the command 
`w32tm /resync /force`  but when I do I get the following error. 

`Sending resync command to local computer
The computer did not resync because no time data was available.`

I have no idea why.  This makes be think that maybe Windows IoT is using something else to get the current time.   I really have not clue.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows IoT hub only requires 2-second resolution to prevent auth errors. Rather than forcing a resync every hour, you just need to configure the w32tm to use the same NTP servers as your RPis:

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org 1.pool.ntp.org 2.pool.ntp.org" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
```

Note the removal of time.windows.com.  It is critical here to pass the /update flag otherwise the change will not be activated.  From the w32tm docs:

> *Changes to configuration are not used by Windows Time unless the service is restarted or the /update switch is used.*

Answer (score 0):

Those darn error messages. Instead of saying that there are no servers in the list to connect to - it generically returns no time data was found :D

Try this command with your resync/force flags

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.windows.time.com 1.pool.ntp.org" /resync /force
```

On startup there must be something similar supplying NTP servers.

You can use any time server you like even a local NTP server if you can set one up.